# TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Tags: python-2.7

```
id_list=[['ABC'], ['ABC'], ['ABC-D', 'YT', 'ITS'], ['ABCDEF'], ['ABC', 'DEF'], ['ZYZA']]
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list
I tried converting id_list to a tuple since I can pass only immutable as keys to the dictionary but that did not work too.

```
model_dict = {}
id_list=[]
for line in fr:
for item in id_list:
  match = re.search(r'%s' % item, line, re.I)
  if match:
    my_line = model_dict[item] + '  => ' +  line
    fw.write(my_line)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 57, in 
    my_line = id_list[item] + '  => ' +  line

Comment: your question is not clear and your code example is not complete.  What is the full traceback, or where is it occurring (I assume line 3 of your code).  What is item?  (I assume a list based on the traceback but am uncertain)

Comment: @VinceWest sorry about that, made the question and the code more understandable.

Comment: looks like you're going to have a new traceback problem... `model_dict`[item] is still going to to be problematc as you are trying to look up a dict item with a list

Comment: yea, I tried converting id_list to a tuple, tuple(id_list) and passed it as key to the dict, but still hitting 
 my_line = model_dict[item] + '  => ' +  line
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: your code still has issues.  Indentation is wrong after `for line in fr:`.  `model_dict` is empty so you can't look anything up in an empty dict.  `item` is still a list so you can't use it as the index for either another list or a dict.  Perhaps if you posted a complete working code bit, would be a little more clear what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

your basic problem is here:

```
for item in id_list:  # id_list is a list of lists so item is a list
...
    model_dict[item]  # item is a list
```

list items must be indexed with an integer: `mylist[0]`

whereas dict items must be indexed with a string: `mydict["index"]`